# Latitude and longitude is not taking in when the map is loaded in webview during on click

Tags: android, google-maps

In my application am loading the map in webview ,while loading  am passing the latitude and longitude value along with the URL  but in my application it doesn't getting the latitude and longitude value please help .My code is given below.

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    TextView tvItemName;
    Spinner spin1,spin2;
    String spinnertext,spinnertext2;
    WebView web;
    Button go;
    public double lat = 0; 
    public double lng = 0; 
    public double lat2 = 0; 
    public double lng2 = 0; 
    LatLng source,destination;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2,container, false);
        spin1=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.source_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource
        (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin2=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> destinationadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.destination_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        destinationadapter.setDropDownViewResource
        (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin1.setAdapter(adapter);
        spin2.setAdapter(destinationadapter);
        spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                spinnertext=spin1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Log.e("aaaa", ""+spinnertext);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                spinnertext2=spin2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Log.e("aaaa", ""+spinnertext2);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        web = (WebView)view. findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        web.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?");
        go=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.gobutton);
        go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + spinnertext + "&sensor=false";
                    Log.e("xxxx", ""+uri);
                    uri = uri.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response;
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    try {
                        response = client.execute(httpGet);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                        int b;
                        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
                        }
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());

                     lng = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                                .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                                .getDouble("lng");

                        lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                                .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                                .getDouble("lat");
                        Log.e("aaaaa", ""+lng);
                        Log.e("bbbb", ""+lat);
                        source=new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String uri2 = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + spinnertext2 + "&sensor=false";
                    Log.e("xxxx", ""+uri2);
                    uri2 = uri2.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                    HttpGet httpGet2 = new HttpGet(uri2);
                    HttpClient client2 = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response2;
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder2 = new StringBuilder();

                    try {
                        response2 = client2.execute(httpGet2);
                        HttpEntity entity = response2.getEntity();
                        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                        int b;
                        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                            stringBuilder2.append((char) b);
                        }
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JSONObject jsonObject2 = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        jsonObject2 = new JSONObject(stringBuilder2.toString());

                        lng2 = ((JSONArray)jsonObject2.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                                .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                                .getDouble("lng");

                        lat2 = ((JSONArray)jsonObject2.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                                .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                                .getDouble("lat");
                        Log.e("aaaaa", ""+lng2);
                        Log.e("bbbb", ""+lat2);
    destination=new LatLng(lat2, lng2);
//      new GetRouteTask().execute();


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();


                }
                    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

                    web.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=lat,lng" + "&daddr=lat,lng2");
Log.e("lngvalue", ""+lng);
Log.e("latvalue", ""+lat);
            }
        });
                return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove
 `web.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?");`

And it is better to use asynctask to load json from url...